# WHERE date BETWEEN (a year ago) AND (now)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query where I need to pull all results where the date is between now and a year ago. So if the query is run tomorrow, the results are going to be a little bit different than they were if it was run today. If I run it today, it would basically be like saying "where the date is between 6/1/2015 and 6/1/2016." Tomorrow, between 6/2/2015 and 6/2/2016, and so on.

I figured I could format it just the same as a regular `WHERE` clause involving dates. This is what I have:

```
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN (DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()) AND (GetDATE())
```

First, I'm not sure if the `DATEADD()` part is what I should use -- I just tried it based on what I was reading on another forum. Second, I've got a red squiggly telling me I've got a syntax error near `AND`.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD` and it is aware of leap years so adding years to a date should be safe even if ran on a leap year (although I still prefer to stay extra safe and add days -- depends on how you want it to behave when ran on leap year).

The reason for the syntax error is your parenthesis. I count **five** staring but only **four** closing. I think you want

```
 BETWEEN DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()) AND GetDATE()
```

Comment: ~facepalm~ it's always the little things, isn't it? Now if only it could just *tell* you it's the parentheses that are the problem instead of being all vague. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra paranthesis `(` in the query.

```
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN cast(DATEADD(yyyy,-1,GETDATE()) as date) AND cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

To ignore the time part of the date, use `cast` to convert `getdate()` and the result of subtracting one year as `date`. This assumes the datatype of `createdate` is `date`.

Comment: This won't really work on leap years.  (Which admittedly will be difficult to solve for).

Answer (score 1):

use the year as you have it, or months.  Don't use days because it won't account for leap years:

```
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

or

```
WHERE CreateDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-12,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```