# Select specific dates SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report that I should run every month, and select data from 21st of the same month of last year till 20th of the current month, current year.
i.e. it's August 29 now and today I need to run my report, but I want it to show only data from 08.21.2016-08.20.2017  and when I run it on September I want data from 09.20.2016-09.21.2017 ...

I was using

```
Select *
from invt
where DATE > (GETDATE()-365)
```

but it it's approximate, and I have to run report exactly on 20th of each month.

Any idea how to do it ?
TIA

Comment: probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575216/where-date-between-a-year-ago-and-now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM invt
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN 
       DATEADD(YEAR,-1,DATEADD(DAY,19,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)))
   AND DATEADD(DAY,20, DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, GETDATE()),0))
```

Looks scary, but its basically doing simple things:

For the 20th of last year:

- Get current date
- just take the month (beginning of month)
- add 19 days (now we are on 20th of current month)
- substract one year

Pretty the same logic for the 21st of current month. just without substracting one year.

Comment: oh, great! This is what I needed. Thx for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if 2012+

```
Where Date between format(DateAdd(YEAR,-1,GetDate()),'yyyy-MM-21')
               and format(GetDate(),'yyyy-MM-20')
```

The date would be `2016-08-21 and 2017-08-20`

Comment: You should avoid use of the FORMAT function. There's been a fair bit of testing and performs, horribly compared to CAST or CONVERT.

Comment: @JasonA.Long Fully aware of the performance of Format().  HOWEVER this will be called/resolved ONCE not record by record.

Comment: Fair enough... But, will the OP be aware of this the next time when they need to do this in a correlated sub-query or cross apply?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use the DATEFROMPARTS function...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.MyTable mt
WHERE 
    mt.SomeDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) -1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the 21st of the current month using:

```
dateadd(day, 21 + 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
```

If you want from one year ago:

```
where date < dateadd(day, 21 + 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)) and
      date >= dateadd(year, 1, dateadd(day, 21 + 1 - day(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 19
DECLARE @PriorDate datetime = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @CurrentDate) + 1

SELECT @CurrentDate, @PriorDate
```